# How to get the last message of the user's conversations and group it in a list in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to get the last message between one user and another, that message is in a collection called chats, there are the conversations between all the members, but I want to filter so that only the last message between one user and another appears. Any way to get this in mongodb?

For example, I want to get the last messages sent/received for the user Carlos. I want to get a list like this

> Example:

```
Chat between John Doe and me
John Doe: Hi

Chat between Max and me
Max: Hello

Chat between Jessica and me
Owner: Hello Jessica
```

> Model

```
1. owner = ObjectId
2. recipient = ObjectId
3. content = Message content
4. createdAt / updatedAt = Autogenerate
```

I am currently trying this, but the error is that I get the last message received to the user and the last message the user sent to that user as well

> Code I am trying

```
const chatData = await this.chatModel
  .find({ $or: [{ owner: userId }, { recipient: userId }] })
  .populate('owner', DEFAULT_POPULATE_SELECT_USER)
  .populate('recipient', DEFAULT_POPULATE_SELECT_USER)
  .sort({ createdAt: 'desc' })
  .select({ __v: false })
  .lean();

const chatLog: ChatModel[] = chatData.reduce((unique, item: any) => {
  if (!item.recipient) return unique;
  return unique.some((x) => x.recipient._id == item.recipient._id) ? unique : [...unique, item];
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

**Sample User Schema**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    name: String,
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date
}
```

**Sample Chat Schema**

```
{
    owner: ObjectId,
    recipient: ObjectId,
    content: String
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date
}
```

**Query**

```
const userId = ObjectId('xxxx...')
await chatModel.aggregate([
    { $match: { $or: [ { owner: userId }, { recipient: userId }] } },
    { $addFields: {
        me: { $cond: [ { $ne: [ '$owner', userId ] }, '$recipient', '$owner' ] },
        other: { $cond: [ { $ne: [ '$owner', userId ] }, '$owner', '$recipient' ] },
    } },
    { $group: { _id: { me: '$me', other: '$other' }, document: { $last: '$$ROOT' } } },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$document' } },
    { $lookup: { from: 'users', let: { owner: '$owner' }, as: 'ownerInfo', pipeline: [ { $match: { $expr: { $and: [ { $eq: [ '$_id', '$$owner' ] } ] } } } ] } },
    { $unwind: '$ownerInfo' },
    { $lookup: { from: 'users', let: { recipient: '$recipient' }, as: 'recipientInfo', pipeline: [ { $match: { $expr: { $and: [ { $eq: [ '$_id', '$$recipient' ] } ] } } } ] } },
    { $unwind: '$recipientInfo' },
    { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } }
])
```